# Modifying PhpStorm's UI Theme to match the Colors and Fonts Theme

Tags: themes, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a *Colors & Fonts* theme I pulled in from [daylerees](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes). I imported the theme in to my `~/.WebIde90/config/colors/` folder. As seen in the screenshot below, I am using Color IDE which changes my *Project* navigation to the same color.

[image]

My problem is I can't get my top menu bar (ie: the one containing *File*, *Edit*, etc.) to change to the same color theme. I opened up my settings, and under `Appearance & Behavior > Appearance`, there is no matching theme under the UI Options. My only options are Alloy, Darkula, GTK and Intellij.

**Is there any way to change the *UI Theme* to match the *Colors and Fonts* theme?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no customisation interface of any kind for GUI themes (also known as [Look & Feel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_look_and_feel) in Java Swing applications).

Basically -- everything is inside the theme. If you want to change it -- you will have to make your own (which is not an easy task as you need to make sure it will work OK in IDEA products, which may have some specifics) or hack the existing one (just changing colors should not be hard). This is actually one of the reasons why such plugins like "Color IDE" exists in first place.

You can change interface fonts at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Override default fonts by`.

---

I may suggest you to look at custom (modified Darcula) dark GUI & Editor themes at https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains . Please note that latest EAP builds (PhpStorm v10) are not fully supported yet -- only stable versions ATM (which is v9 for PhpStorm).